# if $z\in \mathbb{C}$ , then $\bar{z} \in \mathbb{Q}(z)$ [finding $x^3 + bx + c$ splitting field degree]

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I think it suppose to be really straight forward however I can't find a way to justify it.
Let $p$ be an irreducible polynomial $x^3 + bx + c \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $b>0$. Then by  deriving it as a real function, one learn that it has only one real root, and two complex roots.
so $p(x) = (x-r)(x^2+dx+e)$ when $r$ is $p's$ real root and  $z,\bar{z}$ are the complex roots.
I wish to show that $\bar{z}\in \mathbb{Q}(z)$ in order to claim that $[\mathbb{Q}(z,\bar{z}):\mathbb{Q}(z)]=2$ (and thus $[\mathbb{Q}(r,z,\bar{z}):\mathbb{Q}] = 3\times2)$.

What I tried to do was using $z = \frac{\bar{z}z}{\bar{z}}$ and the fact that $z^2+dz+e=0$, and thus $(\frac{\bar{z}z}{\bar{z}})^2+d\frac{\bar{z}z}{\bar{z}} +e=0\Rightarrow  (z\bar{z})^2+d(\bar{z}^2)+e\bar{z}^2=0$ , but I don't find a way to go on.

---

Edit:

Well a counter example appears in comments.
My intention was to demonstrate that the rank of the splitting field must be $6$ , so I'll explain a way around it (cause $\mathbb{Q}(z,\bar{z})\neq \mathbb{Q(z)} $ generally).
In case $r$ is a real root, then $p(x)/(x-r)\in \mathbb{Q}(r)$ due to:
$(x-r)(x^2+dx+e)=x^3+bx+c \Rightarrow x^3 + (d-r)x^2 + (e-rd)x -re = x^3+bx+c$ $\Rightarrow d=r , e=c/(-r)$ when $c\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Now $\mathbb{Q}(r)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and  $x^2+dx+e$ is irreducible, as a polynomial of degree 2 without roots in $\mathbb{Q}(r)$ (complex roots). So,   $[\mathbb{Q}(r)[x] / \langle x^2+dx+e\rangle :\mathbb{Q}(r)] = 2$ and $\mathbb{Q}(r)[x]/ \langle x^2+dx+e\rangle \cong (\mathbb{Q}(r))(z) = \mathbb{Q}(r,z)$ when $z$ is a root of $x^2+dx+e$.

A polynomial of degree 2 as a roots, thus it splits over $\mathbb{Q}(r,z)$ thus $\mathbb{Q}(r,z,\bar{z}) = \mathbb{Q}(r,z)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(r,z):\mathbb{Q} = [\mathbb{Q}(r,z):\mathbb{Q}(r)][\mathbb{Q}(r):\mathbb{Q}] = 2\times3 = 6$.

For the counter example with $x^3-2$ we get that $\mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, 2^{1/3}\omega) = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}, 2^{1/3}\bar{\omega}) = \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/3}\omega,  2^{1/3} \bar{\omega})$

Comment: It's not true: if $\alpha$ is a non-real root of $z^3=2$, then $\overline\alpha\notin\Bbb Q(\alpha)$.

Comment: $x^3+bx+c = (x-z_1)(x-z_2)(x-z_3)$ then $[\mathbb{Q}(z_j):\mathbb{Q}] = 3$ and  either $z_2 \in \mathbb{Q}(z_1)$ in which case $\mathbb{Q}(z_1,z_2,z_3) = \mathbb{Q}(z_j)$ or $z_2 \not\in \mathbb{Q}(z_1)$ and  $[\mathbb{Q}(z_1,z_2,z_3):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(z_1,z_2):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(z_1,z_2):\mathbb{Q}(z_1)][\mathbb{Q}(z_1):\mathbb{Q}]=6$. If one of the roots is complex then the real root cannot generate the splitting field so it is $6$.